# admob help for IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, admob

I want to create advertise for my company on IOS application .

I heard about Admob is it free? If so, how do  I use it in my IOS application any ideas?

Comment: Did you do any research on the topic before posting?

Comment: You can find the documentation here: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's totally free. you have to create account on admob. look at this [link](http://www.admob.com/). It also contain example to how to integrate your AdMob into ios app. One more Ad Container available for mobile name [Adwhirl](http://www.adwhirl.com/). which contain different ads like Admob, iAd, InMobi etc. All ads in One container. The examples are also avaolable